# Detect if menu bar is hidden or visible

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, menubar

Is there a way in Cocoa to receive a notification (or something similar) when the menu bar becomes hidden or visible? I tried looking around and have not found any information on this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by using Carbon's menu event handlers.

I registered for events `kEventMenuBarHidden` and `kEventMenuBarShown` under the class `kEventClassMenu`.

Comment: How did you register for the events?

Answer (score 2):

Optionally watch out for (Cocoa) notifications for an object of class `NSStatusBarWindow` and notifications like

- [`NSWindowDidChangeOcclusionStateNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWindowDidChangeOcclusionStateNotification)
- [`NSWindowWillCloseNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWindowWillCloseNotification)

to get notified when the menu bar showing or hiding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please elaborate on how to implement notifications for the `NSStatusBarWindow`; I could not find find that class.

Comment: So NSStatusBarWindow is part of Apple's private framework, is there a way to do this so that the app can be posted to the appstore?

Comment: No guarantee of course but all we're doing in our app is checking for the string `NSStatusBarWindow` to identify the class… no harm comparing strings :-)

Comment: I like your thinking :D. But how do you observe these notifications on all windows to check for the `NSStatusBarWindow `? I only can get notifications on my application's window. (Thanks for all your help)

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the current state of the menu bar, another approach is to use the [`visibleFrame` property of `NSScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/1388369-visibleframe):

> The returned rectangle is always based on the current user-interface settings and does not include the area currently occupied by the dock and menu bar.

However, this won't be sufficient by itself if you need to be notified of menu bar visibility changes.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the correct approach to this is to use Key-Value Observing (KVO) to observe the `presentationOptions` or `currentSystemPresentationOptions` property of the application object (`NSApp` or `[NSApplication sharedApplication]`). When that changes, check its value to see if it includes `NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar` or `NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar`. If it does, then the menu is hidden (or hides when the cursor is not near the top of the main screen.

The difference between  `presentationOptions` and `currentSystemPresentationOptions` is whether you're interested in whether the calling app has hidden its menu bar or whether the active app (which may be another app) has hidden its menu bar. The latter indicates whether the user can see *any* menu bar.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the presence of the AutoHideMenuBar options seem to correspond only to whether the auto hide button in macOS settings is checked, and I can't seem to find a circumstance where the HideMenuBar option is present, regardless of whether or not the menu bar is on screen.